# Update link preview image for iTunes app link

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app and I am trying to update the image shown in the iMessage link preview. I can't seem to find how to do this.

I'm assuming this can be done by rearranging the "app preview" content from within iTunes Connect, however, the current image shown in the link preview is of the second "app preview" image (within iTunes Connect) and not the first.

The first "app preview" piece is a video. Will Apple use the first non-video "app preview" item for the "link preview" image within iTunes? Or is there another way to update the "link preview" image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so through experimentation I've found the answer to this.

Apple provides the meta-data for iMessage to use to show the link-preview thumbnail. That meta-data uses the first screenshot within AppStoreConnect (iTunesConnect) as the thumbnail for all previews of your app's store link.

This is confusing since any app-previews (i.e. videos) will NOT have any affect on what is seen within the iMessage link preview thumbnail. This is true even if you specify a specific thumbnail for the app-preview within AppStoreConnect.

So if you want to update the thumbnail for your app's store link you need to update the first screenshot for your app. It will probably take a while to get indexed (took mine around 24 hours)

Hope this helps someone!